# Deploy a console executable to Tempdir in a store app

Tags: wpf, vb.net, windows-store-apps

I have just finalised a WPF vb.net application on code behind, that is going to be distributed via MS Store with windows app package project.
The app consumes and redirects StdIn and StdOut of an old fortran console executable, for which I lost the source code.
Locally, it works as expected.
The executable can't be copied and executed in the userspace though, because of safety constraints of the app deployment.
I can copy the console exe to the user temp folder, but that probably has to be done at install time. That's where I'm lost, and appreciate some guidance.

Thanks to all who may help.

Comment: Maybe you can use the [AppFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.localuserappdatapath?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: I can, but how can I deploy a .exe into it?

Comment: You could put exe in your WPF project and then use process in code to start this exe.This [Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2016/11/28/desktop-bridge-multiple-desktop-processes-a-single-uwp-container/) may give you some help.